# netem loopback interface reordering packets

Tags: networking, wireshark, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, packets

I have two apps communicating over UDP on the same host and I would like to send packets with varying delays (jitter) but no out of order packets. I have this rule for loopback interface:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1: netem delay 10ms 100ms
```

This seems to create the jitter successfully; however, there are out of order packets.. Basically I would like to recieve the packets on the receiver side in the order that they are sent from the sender, with just varying delay, i.e. with jitter.

I tried some basic reorder commands.. when I use reorder 100%, it does the reorder but there is no jitter in this case. If I use reorder command with anything less than 100%, then there is out of order packets.

It says [here](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#How_to_reorder_packets_based_on_jitter.3F) that if execute the following command, the packets will stay in order:

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev lo parent 1:1 pfifo limit 1000
```

But I still get out of order packets. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: btw, how did you setup emulation on same host? (what's `lo` and `handle 1` and how can I add these?) I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**(§1)** According to the official documentation - [delay section](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Delay_distribution) this code
`# tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms 10ms.`

> ... causes the added delay to be 100ms ± 10m

In your code the second `ms` command line argument is greater than the first.

---

**(§2)** Additionally, under the [packet re-ordering section](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem#Packet_re-ordering) this code
`# tc qdisc change dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms 75ms`

> ... will cause some reordering. If the first packet gets a random delay of 100ms (100ms base - 0ms jitter) and the second packet is sent 1ms later and gets a delay of 50ms (100ms base - 50ms jitter); the second packet will be sent first.

---

**Educated guess:** (didn't test)
Switch the position of your last two arguments from
`sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1: netem delay 10ms 100ms`
to
`sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root handle 1: netem delay 100ms 10ms`

Although according to **(§2)** it is still possible that your packets can get reordered if you send them back-to-back in under 20ms: 1st packet gets 100+10=110ms delay, 2nd packet that you send 1ms later gets 100-10=90ms delay; 2nd packet will arrive before 1st one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it seems it is not possible to avoid packet reordering with netem. I was trying to mimic real world scenarios where jitter occurs quite often but not so much packet reordering.